# Could not resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:20.12.+. in Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments

Earlier my project was running without error but today i am getting following error. I would appreciate if anyone can help to get out of this issue.

**Note- I am not using jCenter in my app, payment sdk flutter_stripe using jCenter**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
       > Could not resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:20.12.+.
         Required by:
             project :app > project :stripe_android
          > Failed to list versions for com.stripe:stripe-android.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/stripe/stripe-android/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/stripe/stripe-android/maven-metadata.xml'.
                   > Read timed out
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 47s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/stripe/stripe-android/maven-metadata.xml is not working even on my browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My flutter Android build broke all sudden with a gradle error, with no changes to the gradle configuration on my part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688532/my-flutter-android-build-broke-all-sudden-with-a-gradle-error-with-no-changes-t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/1000#issuecomment-1296608139) is a link to a solution in the flutter_stripe issue list

You need to add the following line inside app level **build.gradle** file:

```
constraints { implementation('com.stripe:stripe-android') { version { strictly '20.11.0' } } }
constraints { implementation('com.stripe:financial-connections') { version { strictly '20.11.0' } } }
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and for two days I tried to figure out what the cause was. The problem is jcenter. Not so why it decided not to work. I solved it by replacing with mavenCentral in your project level build.gradle.

Reference: [My flutter Android build broke all sudden with a gradle error, with no changes to the gradle configuration on my part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688532/my-flutter-android-build-broke-all-sudden-with-a-gradle-error-with-no-changes-t)

If you also have the "Stripe" plugin, you have to add [this extension](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/1000#issuecomment-1296608139) as well as the user indicated above

Answer (score 1):

Jcenter seems down today.I guess you should switch to mavenCentral instead.